# How to Using distinct @table type or remove duplicate from custom user table type?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

I use pass table type to store procedure for bulk insert and update (Merge).
But as you know , in Merge statement all records insert with one transaction , for example if i have 2 duplicate record in my custom @table type instead of insert one of them , insert 2 duplicate Record ...
Now I want to merge @table type records before insert them .
in my program case I cant merge more than 1M record because i get memory exception.
However this is my SP code :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO ALTER PROC [dbo].[Mysp_MergeInsert_tblRelationship]
      @tblrelationship TBLRELATIONSHIPTYPE READONLY AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        MERGE INTO tblRelationship tM
        USING @tblrelationship tS
        ON tM.MasterUserId = tS.MasterUserId
       AND tM.userId = tS.userId
        WHEN MATCHED
              THEN UPDATE SET tM.Follows = tS.Follows,
                              tM.FollowBy = tS.FollowBy
        WHEN NOT MATCHED
              THEN INSERT VALUES( tS.MasterUserId, tS.userId, tS.Follows, tS.FollowBy );
    END;
```

I can delete duplicate with this sql code , but not when @tblrelationship is readonly , and cannot use merge when @tblrelationship is Not readonly

```
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY userId)
        FROM @tblrelationship
        )
        delete FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

did you know any solution to solve it ? 
Thanks .

Comment: create a `temp table` or `table variable` and insert the records from `@tblrelationship`.  Now you can remove the duplicate from `temp table` or `table variable`

Comment: why don't you remove,duplicate record while creating data for table type.like in front end.This is best.Second option is what @MM93 said.
I want to hear third option.

Comment: hats deference between table variable and table type ??! both of them are data that you can select query from them ! also i need best performance , i think this solution slow my SP to much

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple subquery with DISTINCT in it to do merge? Should work.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC dbo.Mysp_MergeInsert_tblRelationship
(
  @tblrelationship TBLRELATIONSHIPTYPE READONLY AS
)
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  BEGIN TRY
    MERGE INTO tblRelationship tM
    USING (
      SELECT DISTINCT UserId, MasterUserId, Follows, FollowBy
      FROM @tblrelationship
      ) tS
    ON tM.MasterUserId = tS.MasterUserId
      AND tM.userId = tS.userId
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET tM.Follows = tS.Follows,
                tM.FollowBy = tS.FollowBy
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT VALUES( tS.MasterUserId, tS.userId, tS.Follows, tS.FollowBy);
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
  END CATCH
END
```

P.S. I've added TRY/CATCH to your procedure. It's recommended practice to do that. In this case CATCH statement is a simple SELECT, but you could write errors into some Audit table in order to track them.

Comment: I'll do a quick update on my answer. You should be using TRY/CATCH in your SPs.

Comment: But also it insert duplicate !!

Comment: It shouldn't. Update your answer and provide more details. What you have , how your declared table looks like and what does it produce.