# How remove from user database type duplicate records with id 221

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ImportSurveys] 
  @surveys udtSurveys readonly
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Surveys
        (Funzione,
         Id_Intervento,
         Titolo_Intervento,
         Titolo_Rilievo,
         ImportDownloadDate,
         Oggetto_Valutato,
         Id_Oggetto_Valutato,
         Id,
         Id_Banca,
         Cod_ABI,
         Legal_Entity,
         Title,
         Descrizione_Rilievo,
         Azione_di_Mitigazione,
         Owner_Azione_di_Mitigazione,
         Utente_Censimento,
         Severita_Rilievo,
         Data_Scadenza,
         Anno,
         StatusId)
    SELECT Funzione, 
        Id_Intervento,
        Titolo_Intervento,
        Titolo_Rilievo, 
        DataDownload,
        Oggetto_Valutato,
        Id_Oggetto_Valutato,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(450), Id) + Funzione,
        Id_Banca,
        Cod_ABI,
        Legal_Entity,
        Titolo_Rilievo,
        Descrizione_Rilievo,
        Azione_di_Mitigazione,
        Owner_Azione_di_Mitigazione,
        Utente_Censimento,
        Severita_Rilievo,
        Data_Scadenza,
        Anno,
        2 
    FROM @surveys sur
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * from dbo.Surveys WHERE  dbo.Surveys.Id = (CONVERT(nvarchar(450), sur.Id) + Funzione))
END
```

udtSurveys is used like params by stored procedure.

Before inserting records into table `surveys` I need to remove all duplicate column with Id from udtSurveys.

Would you please show me an example of how use `group by` or another way to remove duplicated records before inserting to table?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705996/possible-to-do-a-delete-with-a-having-clause

Comment: stored procedure params  `@surveys(udtSurveys)` returns two identical records with Id 224. Just I need to remove one. 
I have already been checking existed  records in my database `surveys` with `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. 
But before I need remove duplicate records from @surveys(udtSurveys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a CTE to filter all the duplicate rows from @surveys parameter.

I've updated your query with a `cte_tbl` by assuming you want to keep the original rows and remove its duplicates.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ImportSurveys] 
  @surveys udtSurveys readonly
AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH cte_tbl AS (
        SELECT  *,
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Funzione) 
        FROM @surveys sur
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                            FROM dbo.Surveys
                            WHERE dbo.Surveys.Id = (CONVERT(nvarchar(450), sur.Id) + Funzione))
    )

    INSERT INTO Surveys
        (Funzione,
         Id_Intervento,
         Titolo_Intervento,
         Titolo_Rilievo,
         ImportDownloadDate,
         Oggetto_Valutato,
         Id_Oggetto_Valutato,
         Id,
         Id_Banca,
         Cod_ABI,
         Legal_Entity,
         Title,
         Descrizione_Rilievo,
         Azione_di_Mitigazione,
         Owner_Azione_di_Mitigazione,
         Utente_Censimento,
         Severita_Rilievo,
         Data_Scadenza,
         Anno,
         StatusId)
    SELECT Funzione, 
        Id_Intervento,
        Titolo_Intervento,
        Titolo_Rilievo, 
        DataDownload,
        Oggetto_Valutato,
        Id_Oggetto_Valutato,
        CONVERT(nvarchar(450), Id) + Funzione,
        Id_Banca,
        Cod_ABI,
        Legal_Entity,
        Titolo_Rilievo,
        Descrizione_Rilievo,
        Azione_di_Mitigazione,
        Owner_Azione_di_Mitigazione,
        Utente_Censimento,
        Severita_Rilievo,
        Data_Scadenza,
        Anno,
        2 
    FROM cte_tbl 
    WHERE RN = 1 -- will only fetch the distinct id-rows
END
```

Comment: thank you. 
Would you explain what do this code:
`WITH cte_tbl AS (
        SELECT  *,
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Funzione)` ?

Comment: `cte_tbl` is the [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) I've created with an added ROW_NUMBER column(RN).  The purpose of RN column is to mark the duplicated rows. `PARTITION` will reset the ROW_NUMBER when there is a change in a specific column. `ORDER BY` can be anything in your case. It is used to identify the very first row in a set of duplicates. You can read all about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to nest the query which gets the duplicate record like. Then inner select gets you the id if there is there are more than 1 record.

```
declare @id varchar = 'ABC'
delete from [dbo].[TABLE_NAME]
where id in (Select id from [TABLE_NAME]
              where [id] = @id
              group by id
              having count(*) > 1
             )
```

Comment: thank you. and how use records after removing to insert in database?

Comment: Bit confusing ,, if surveys is an id field then why are you suing it in "FROM @surveys" , if its a table then you can select the distinct record.

Comment: hm... `@surveys` is user datatable type PARAMS OF STORED PROCEDURE.
Could you show example with distinct?

Comment: Use a select distinct col1, col2 ... from @survey.. look at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843446/how-to-using-distinct-table-type-or-remove-duplicate-from-custom-user-table-typ